# WSO2 ESB alters the wsdl

Tags: wso2, esb

I have a backend service which I configure as a proxy service in WSO2 ESB.

The ESB exposes slightly different wsdl, which is also valid and works as expected.

The problem is I can't use my old stubs with the ESB wsdl because of the changed structure. I want to create the service in such a way that the wsdl from ESB is EXACTLY the same as my endpoint service.

Is such approch poissible or do I need to generate again the stubs (this would require a lot of effort in my case)?

EDIT: The difference in the WSDL between endpoint and esb wsdl
1. For example my endpoint has following tags

```
<xs:element name=", - Endpoint
<xsd:element name=  - ESB
```

2. Another difference is:

```
<wsdl:service name="CasesServiceService"> - Endpoint
<wsdl:service name="CasesService"> - ESB
```

3. Port names:

```
<wsdl:port name="CasesServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="tns:CasesServiceSoap11Binding">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:CasesServiceServiceSoapBinding" name="CasesServicePort">
```

Comment: Stubs are used from client end.. Dint get clearly what you mean by " I want to create the service in such a way that the wsdl from ESB is EXACTLY the same as my endpoint service.".  If your wsdl is changed then you need to regenerate the stubs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I didn't explain it well, see the edited original post, please. The problem is I don't want to generate again the stubs (because it will be very time consuming), I want just to change the endpoint URL in the stubs so that they continue to function.

Comment: I dont think you can use same stubs to invoke the proxy.. What is the purpose of adding the wsdl to the proxy? Noramlly, if we dont like to expose some operations of the backend service, we will edit the wsdl and attch the wsdl to proxy with the only allowed opeartions. In your case, i dont think there is a valid reason to attch a wsdl to your proxy rather than a simple name cahnge.:) Just remove it.

Comment: The only case AFAIK you can use the older stubs is, if you changed the method implementation and not changed any operation names or parametes you dont need to regenarte the stubs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make WSO2 ESB keep the same WSDL contract with the exact same services / ports names, you can edit the Apache Synapse configuration file for your proxy service directly. Just click on "Source View" in the WSO2 ESB interface and add the following parameters to the `<proxy>` node:

```
<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
<parameter name="modifyUserWSDLPortAddress">true</parameter>
```

This will make it use the original WSDL and modify only the port address so it points to the bus.

The [relevant documentation is here](http://synapse.apache.org/userguide/config.html#ProxyServiceConfig).