# Validation error with WSO2 ESB generated WSDL

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I created a proxy service with WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 using a complex WSDL using a WSDL import and a lot of schema imports. I can import the original WSDL to SoapUI but not the one generated from the proxy service. WSDL validation gives error

> ERROR - RPCMessageReceiver WSDLException (at
>   /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:message[1](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-12030)/wsdl:part):
>   faultCode=UNBOUND_PREFIX: Unable to determine namespace of
>   'null:UpdateConsumerByDMS_v1'.

I found similar problem from https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-12030. How to solve the problem? Any help appreciated.

Best regards,

Teemu

I think I could get over this by using the original WSDL with proxy parameters

```
<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
<parameter name="modifyUserWSDLPortAddress">true</parameter>
```

[WSO2 ESB alters the wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246877/wso2-esb-alters-the-wsdl)

Answer (score 1):

Keep the original wsdl file in registry, lets say in conf/myresources folder and then use the below after target.

```
<publishWSDL key="conf:myresources/<wsdl_file>.wsdl"/>
<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
<parameter name="modifyUserWSDLPortAddress">true</parameter>
<parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. I solved it by doing two things:

1) Add all schema in the registry like: /_system/governance/services and add your wsdl there too.

2) In your proxy service, use pick from registry and add in Reference Key something like

> gov:/services/xxx.wsdl

In the resources, under WSDL resource, add all your schema like

> schema1.xsd   gov:/services/schema1.xsd

It will probably works.